# Why does my pthread_cond_wait and signal work like it should? It seems that I reached a deadlock instead

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

```
void * thread1()
{
   pthread_mutex_lock(mutex1);
   pthread_mutex_lock(mutex2);

   while (someCondition)
       pthread_cond_wait(&condVar, &condMutex1);

   pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex1);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex2); 

}   

void * thread1()
{
   pthread_mutex_lock(mutex1);
   pthread_mutex_lock(mutex2);

   if (someCondition)
       pthread_cond_signal(&condVar, &cmutex1);

   pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex1);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex2); 

}
```

I actually have many lines of code but this is a simplified version. Now, it seems that my program has reached a deadlock and I cannot figure out why... I swear I think I'm using it right. 
1.) My mutex1 was locked when I'm doing it. 
2.) I'm sure it's the same conditional variable I'm using. (I'm accessing the conditional variable through shared memory) OR better yet, is there a way to identify the conditional variable in the different processes?

Comment: There seems to be a lot wrong or missing from the posted code (even if you're just posting a snippet). Are `condMutex1`, `cmutex1` and `mutex1` all supposed to be the same name?  What is signaling the `condVar`?

Comment: They are supposed to be referring to the same thing. However, it's hard to tell since I'm referring to them from shared memory. Is there a way to somehow print the id of my variables to double check?

Comment: These threads are in two different processes btw.

Comment: But as of now, does my approach seem correct? The only possible error I can think of is if somehow, the two conditional variables that I think I'm referring to (again, through shared memory) is not actually what I think it is. How can I check if I'm truly referring to the same thing from two different processes?

Comment: First thread locks `mutex1` and waits; the seconds thread tries to lock `mutex1` and waits. Both threads are now waiting indefinitely.